# R - How to replace values of a variable with the name of the variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tribble(~a,~b,
             0 ,1,
             1 ,0)
```

Result I want:

```
 a  b
'' 'b'
'a' ''
```

How can I replace values with the variables' name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to replace the 1 with the column names and 0 by blank (`""`), and if the columns are only binary, we can use `map2` to loop through the columns and corresponding column names, then add 1 to the columns and use it as index to replace the 1 with `""` and 2 with the corresponding column names

```
library(tidyverse)
map2_df(df, colnames(df), ~  c('', .y)[.x +1])
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   a     b    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 ""    b    
#2 a     ""
```

Comment: this solution works only when 2 rows, my data have decades of rows.
if df = data.frame(a=c(0,1,0), b= c(1,0,1)) , how can I transform?

Comment: @hyunwoojeong  It will work for any number for rows.  WIth the new example you gave, it is working fine with me

Comment: you're right : ) I wonder why I couldn't find you're right then

Answer (score 2):

You can also try , `replace` function from **BASE R:**, printing nwdf1, you will have your final answer.

```
nwdf <- replace(df,df == 1,names(df))
nwdf1 <- replace(nwdf, nwdf==0, '')
```

Where df is :

```
structure(list(a = c(0, 1), b = c(1, 0)), .Names = c("a", "b"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

**EDIT**:

More generic solution for above question:

```
outputdf <-  data.frame(sapply(names(df), function(x)ifelse(df[,x] == 1, x, '')), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**Output**:

```
 # A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <chr> <chr>
1           b
2     a
```

Comment: this solution works only when 2 rows, my data have decades of rows. if df = data.frame(a=c(0,1,0), b= c(1,0,1)) , how can I transform?

Comment: @hyunwoojeong, see the EDIT

Comment: Wow, thank you~ 
That's what I'm looking for.
I did follows.  

sapply(names(df),function(x) ifelse(df[,x]==1,x,'')) %>% tbl_df